# Merging two Excel VBA Code (Save as PDF + Send Via Outlook)

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, outlook

kindly I have a two `VBA` codes one is to save the printed area as PDF with the same name as the workbook is and save file location is Desktop and it works fine
and I do have another code which start outlook new message and take some specific cell value as subject and another value as body.

The problem is I want the code of the new mail to attach that saved PDF file from code 1 and make the subject to be same as PDF file name.

The save pdf code is:

```
Sub Save_as_pdf()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim s(1) As String
Dim sNewFilePath As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

s(0) = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

If FSO.FileExists(ThisWorkbook.FullName) Then
    '//Change Excel Extension to PDF extension in FilePath
    s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))

    If s(1) <> "" Then
        s(1) = "." & s(1)
        sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), ".pdf")

        '//Export to PDF with new File Path
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=sNewFilePath, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If
Else
    '//Error: file path not found
    MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
End If

Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

... and the second outlook new email code is :

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As     String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub SendEMail()
Dim Email As String, Subj As String
Dim Msg As String, URL As String

Email = " "

Subj = "P.O # " & "-" & Cells(9, 5) & "-" & Cells(15, 2) & "-" & Cells(15, 8) & Cells(15, 7)

Msg = " "
Msg = "Dear Mr. " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Good Day" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Kindly find the attahched P.O to be delivered to " & Cells(10, 12)



'Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
Subj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Subj, " ", "%20")
Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Msg, " ", "%20")

'Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Msg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")

'Create the URL
URL = "mailto:" & Email & "?subject=" & Subj & "&body=" & Msg



'Execute the URL (start the email client)
ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, URL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

'Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
'Application.SendKeys "%s"
End Sub
```

I hope I could clarify my problem fine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :
It changes the PDF export to a function to get the file path and use it as an argument in the other one.
URL method doesn't works with attachments, so below is some code for Outlook(**edited to contain the whole code**)

Preparing mail with Outlook (sorry for french comments):

```
Sub Send_To_Pdf()
Dim PdfPath As String
Dim BoDy As String

BoDy = Msg = "Dear Mr. " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Good Day" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Kindly find the attahched P.O to be delivered to " & Cells(10, 12)


PdfPath = Save_as_pdf
EnvoiMail Right(PdfPath, InStr(1, StrReverse(PdfPath), "\") - 1), "recepient1@domain.com;recepient2@domain.com", , , BoDy, 1, PdfPath
End Sub

Public Function Save_as_pdf() As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim s(1) As String
Dim sNewFilePath As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

s(0) = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

If FSO.FileExists(ThisWorkbook.FullName) Then
    '//Change Excel Extension to PDF extension in FilePath
    s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))

    If s(1) <> "" Then
        s(1) = "." & s(1)
        sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), ".pdf")

        '//Export to PDF with new File Path
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=sNewFilePath, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If
Else
    '//Error: file path not found
    MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
End If

Set FSO = Nothing

Save_as_pdf = sNewFilePath

End Function


Sub EnvoiMail(Subject As String, Destina As String, Optional CCdest As String, Optional CCIdest As String, Optional BoDyTxt As String, Optional NbPJ As Integer, Optional PjPaths As String)
  Dim MonOutlook As Object
  Dim MonMessage As Object
  Set MonOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set MonMessage = MonOutlook.createitem(0)

  Dim PJ() As String
  PJ() = Split(PjPaths, ";")

  With MonMessage
      .Subject = Subject      '"Je suis content"
      .To = Destina           '"marcel@machin.com;julien@chose.com"
      .cc = CCdest            '"chef@machin.com;directeur@chose.com"
      .bcc = CCIdest          '"un.copain@supermail.com;une-amie@hotmail.com"
      .BoDy = BoDyTxt
        If PjPaths <> "" And NbPJ <> 0 Then
            For i = 0 To NbPJ - 1
                'MsgBox PJ(I)
              .Attachments.Add PJ(i)      '"C:\Mes Documents\Zoulie Image.gif"
            Next i
        End If
      .display
      '.send                        '.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  End With                        '?plusieurs?MonMessage.Attachments.Add "D:\Prof\Janvier\Base clients.mdb"

  Set MonOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. but can you please advice where to place those codes? first code in Outlook? a regular module? and the second code in excel? if so i tried but i could assign the excel macro to a button so i wait for you kind reply

Comment: Place everything in excel, they can't communicate if the are in separate applications (they can but it is more complex). Look at the code I added, at the start, it create an Outlook application to be able to interact with it in Excel directly. For your method with URL, Excel should be enough too.

Comment: thanks for your help but after trying the codes it saves as pdf and start the outlook but with no attachments still :(

Comment: Did you use the second part of the code I put (because URL mailto won't add attachment), use the `sub EnvoiMail` with the PJ parameter and the "/" separator for your attachments!

Comment: i think i used the code in a wrong way, if i may not waste your time can you please put the code in a workbook and send me the file so you make sure everything in it`s corrected place and make sure it works as you mean.

Comment: I changed it in the edit, just take the whole code and put it in a module in Excel! ;)

Comment: you know what? you are a genius it worked like a charm actually. thank you very much and please tell me how to mark this problem as solved and rate your answer

Comment: Great! Ok so at the start/top of the answer, you have two arrows (vote up and vote down) and right under it, you will see a tick that is still gray. To validate answer, you need to click on that tick that will become green and you may vote up too! Enjoy SO! ;)

Comment: thank you very much, i selected as solved by it said i need +15 rep to be able to vote up :( sorry actually. one more question please, how to include my signature in the new created message by the code?

Comment: NP mate, it should be better now! ;) For signature, you will find all the info you need in there : http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm

Comment: i really appreciate your prompt replies and perfect answers. once again thank you :)

Comment: Don't mention it ;) Just when you will be a master-coder take some time to answer and up vote what is helpful to you now that you can ;)